# Slow Drive Speeds, and getting to the bottom of it

Tags: windows, usb, troubleshooting, usb-3

I have a SanDisk Extreme Pro 55AF (2nd gen) which supports USB Gen3.2 2x2, which caps at about `20 GBps`.

I found that no matter what cable I use (including the included one), I only get `38 MBps` in windows. My M1 MacBook air gets *reasonable* speeds.

First I thought it was because I went exFAT (for MAC + Windows use), and now even in NFTS I cannot get it past `38 MBps`.

Here are my specs:

- AMD Ryzen 5 5600X
- Windows 11 Home
- MSI XPG X570 Gaming Plus (its site: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-X570-GAMING-PLUS ) (the manual: https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/mb/MPGX570GAMINGPLUS.pdf ) BIOS is updated to the latest as of 4/28/23
- 4x 8GB sticks of some XPG problemaic pro pluses that I will never buy again (crashes unless I use the base clock os 2444, even though up to 5400 was advertised)
  -EVGA FTW3 Ultra 3090
- Gigabyte something something Wifi 6E PCIE card

Here are the 3 drives I tested:

- `C` Drive, CT500P2SSD8 500GB
- `D` Drive, SanDisk Ultra 3D NVMe 1TB (Model: SDSSDH3N-1T00)
- External SanDisk Extreme Pro 55AF (Gen2, 3.2 2x2) 1TB (Model: SDSSDE81-1T00)

My Motherboard has these USB ports on the back

- 2x USB-A 2.0
- 2x USB-A 3.2 Gen1
- 1x USB-A 3.2 Gen2
- 1x USB-C 3.2 Gen2
- 2x USB-A 3.2 Gen1

My C and D drive seem to be functioning at the speeds they were intended to,
but my USB's never perform like they should.

I have attached ATTO screenshots, and have also tried Crystal Disk Mark.

[image: ATTO]

I only have screenshots of the SanDisk external being tested on the USB-C 3.2 gen 2, but no matter which port use, 3.2 gen 1 or 2, or the USB-C 3.2gen2 pictured, I still cap out at 36-42 MBps.

I also attached a screenshot from USB device tree to show that, all the ports support SuperSpeed and are showing up as AMD USB 3.10 (H means slow, S means fast) but none of them are actuall registering or reading as SuperSpeed and are rather showing as standard.

[image: USB Tree]

I checked the BIOS, its up to date, and I didn't see any specific settings to enable 3.2 speeds.
I did also try changing the xHCI in bios from enabled to disabled and it made no difference.

Comment: Try to open Device Manager and in category "Universal Serial Bus Controller" to uninstall all the USB 3.1 extensible host controllers, then reboot to have them reinstalled.

Comment: I just tried, restarted, and it didnt change anything :(

Comment: Could be that your USB controller on your Windows PC is just not fast enough. To prove that this is not the case, you need to have another USB device (XHCI) to use the same port and reach a higher speed.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer but I have two HPs.. one older business i7, one new zbook, and one dell i7.  The business i7 is ABHORRENTLY slow USB even though it is supposed to be USB3  The zbook screams and the dell screams.  All same OS using the same drive.  Sometimes there is nothing you can do. :|